# RHEL7 dockerd remote connection

Tags: docker, iptables, rhel7, firewalld

I'm exploring creating a gateway that can start and stop docker containers on a rhel7 system upon.  I've made changes to my /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service to start docker on an interface with the following.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:23751 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

I'm unable to connect to dockerd to get the status of the containers unless I disable the firewall.  But if I disable the firewall,  I can't start conatiners.

```
Caused by: com.amihaiemil.docker.UnexpectedResponseException: Expected status 204 but got 500 when calling
 http://192.168.1.70:23751/v1.35/containers/e3f0f09269a699ec27bbac8a5027d1383ae15cf64b5e6b649e76be1297cc2535/start. 
Response body was {"message":"driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint hello-service 
(eef135f889322f1899800f19612404e9d8b1f39c7866f31ca5059562aa501bf6):  
(iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 34570 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.40:8080 ! -i br-4982fe847356: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\n (exit status 1))"}
```

I realize there are consequences of running an open tcp port for dockerd.  Before,  I get everything secure,  I would like to get an idea of how a gateway might do something like this.

Does anyone else have experience doing something like this?

Comment: "There are consequences" ==> "anyone who can reach that port has unrestricted root-level access over your system".  "Docker cryptojacking" is a good search term.

Comment: Understood.  I don't plan on making this a finished product without securing it.  This is an exploration of a gateway to start containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I found out that firewalld is blocking that port.
To enable the port, do the following.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2375/tcp
```

> Please note, doing this opens a very large security vulnerability as the commenter above has pointed out.  In my case, this was done behind a firewall where no outside connections can make a connection to inside my network's firewall.  This is still a bad idea, but in this case it is being used to explore some concepts and is turned off when not being used. Please explore the security implications when doing this.
>   Also, the firewall will not save the configuration in the above command unless you use the --permanent argument